# Reactjs screens size problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a problem with Reactjs in the screen sizes.
Actually, the website should work with multiple screens sizes but I notice the components be in nested view. they go across each other.

```
    /* Media Query */
@media (max-width: 1380px){
    html,
    body {
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: normal;
    }
}
```

And how can I determine the screen size?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or illustration of your screens? Also, please share your components' code to ease understanding of your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can't determine screen size from the css, but what you can do is use the following property: `vw` for viewport width and `vh` for viewport height. Then  you can do some math to properly get the behaviour you want.

For instance:

```scss
@media (max-width: 1380px){
    html,
    body {
        max-width: 95vw;
    }
}
```

Here, when the screen width is bellow 1380px, the max width of the body will not exceed 95% of the screen width

Hope it helped you

Comment: The website should work with different screen size small, medium and large So I think I should add min-width.